# Loading NetCDF file into QGIS, file is flipped upside down

Tags: gdal, netcdf, qgis

I have a georeferenced NetCDF file that I am trying to load into QGIS (3.14). I can open the file and load it but the file always renders upside down. I am not sure if this is a problem with my NetCDF file (incorrect georeference) or if this is a bug with QGIS and the GDAL NetCDF driver. I have been able to successfully plot the NetCDF file with a few other programs (`ncview`, python+matplotlib+basemap) and it renders correctly, so I am thinking this is an issue with QGIS. Is there a way to tell QGIS how to treat the file?

I have tried processing my file with `gdal_translate` and experimenting with `-co WRITE_BOTTOMUP=YES` and `-co WRITE_BOTTOMUP=NO`, as follows:

```
gdal_translate -of netcdf -co WRITE_BOTTOMUP=NO NETCDF:"vegetation.nc":veg_class /tmp/OUTPUT_bu_no.nc
```

But in both cases the resulting file still loads upside down (and interestingly in both cases `ncview` then renders the file upside-down as well).

I also discovered another option for the GDAL netcdf driver ([here](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/netcdf.html)), `GDAL_NETCDF_BOTTOMUP=[YES/NO]`, but I am unsure how to send this option to QGIS when it opens the file?

Here is the metadata for the netcdf file I am trying to load, perhaps someone can tell if the georeference info is incorrect:

```
ncdump -h /<path to my file>/vegetation.nc
netcdf vegetation {
dimensions:
    Y = 50 ;
    X = 135 ;
variables:
    int veg_class(Y, X) ;
        veg_class:grid_mapping = "albers_conical_equal_area" ;
    float lat(Y, X) ;
    float lon(Y, X) ;
    int y(Y) ;
        y:standard_name = "projection_y_coordinate" ;
        y:long_name = "y coordinate of projection" ;
        y:units = "m" ;
    int x(X) ;
        x:standard_name = "projection_x_coordinate" ;
        x:long_name = "x coordinate of projection" ;
        x:units = "m" ;
    char albers_conical_equal_area ;
        albers_conical_equal_area:grid_mapping_name = "albers_conical_equal_area" ;
        albers_conical_equal_area:false_easting = 0. ;
        albers_conical_equal_area:false_northing = 0. ;
        albers_conical_equal_area:latitude_of_projection_origin = 50. ;
        albers_conical_equal_area:longitude_of_central_meridian = -154. ;
        albers_conical_equal_area:standard_parallel = 55., 65. ;
        albers_conical_equal_area:longitude_of_prime_meridian = 0. ;
        albers_conical_equal_area:semi_major_axis = 6378137. ;
        albers_conical_equal_area:inverse_flattening = 298.257222101 ;
        albers_conical_equal_area:spatial_ref = "PROJCS[\"NAD83 / Alaska Albers\",GEOGCS[\"NAD83\",DATUM[\"North_American_Datum_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS 1980\",6378137,298.2572221010002,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"7019\"]],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"6269\"]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0],UNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"4269\"]],PROJECTION[\"Albers_Conic_Equal_Area\"],PARAMETER[\"standard_parallel_1\",55],PARAMETER[\"standard_parallel_2\",65],PARAMETER[\"latitude_of_center\",50],PARAMETER[\"longitude_of_center\",-154],PARAMETER[\"false_easting\",0],PARAMETER[\"false_northing\",0],UNIT[\"metre\",1,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9001\"]],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"3338\"]]" ;
        albers_conical_equal_area:GeoTransform = "-137256.2642264267 1000.050170338725 0 2372459.286491414 0 -999.7969847651308 " ;

// global attributes:
        :Conventions = "CF-1.5" ;
        :source = "/home/UA/tcarman2/dvm-dos-tem/./scripts/create_region_input.py::fill_veg_file --xoff -137256.290295 --yoff 2321969.51702" ;
}
```

[image: example file upside down]

Comment: I think netCDF files are referenced from the top left instead of lower left. That might be your issue?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @nmtoken, but the question you linked is from me too - I posted it in impatience as I was waiting for this question to be migrated from Stack Overflow. One of them should likely be deleted...